# Switch rows between two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, row

Let the matrices A and B.

```
A=c(1:5)*matrix(1,5,5)
B=10*A
```

that is,

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5

> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10
[2,]   20   20   20   20   20
[3,]   30   30   30   30   30
[4,]   40   40   40   40   40
[5,]   50   50   50   50   50
```

I would like, for example, to switch the first rows between the matrices A and B, that is

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5

> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]   20   20   20   20   20
[3,]   30   30   30   30   30
[4,]   40   40   40   40   40
[5,]   50   50   50   50   50
```

using a function, and without using any indermediate vector or a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

As per you update in the comment, you can try

```
lapply(
  1:nrow(B),
  function(k) {
    setNames(
      Map(
        function(x, ind,r) {
          x[ind, ] <- r
          x
        },
        list(A, B),
        list(1,k),
        list(B[k, ], A[1, ])
      ), c("A", "B")
    )
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5

[[1]]$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]   20   20   20   20   20
[3,]   30   30   30   30   30
[4,]   40   40   40   40   40
[5,]   50   50   50   50   50


[[2]]
[[2]]$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   20   20   20   20   20
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5

[[2]]$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]   30   30   30   30   30
[4,]   40   40   40   40   40
[5,]   50   50   50   50   50


[[3]]
[[3]]$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   30   30   30   30   30
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5

[[3]]$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10
[2,]   20   20   20   20   20
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]   40   40   40   40   40
[5,]   50   50   50   50   50


[[4]]
[[4]]$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   40   40   40   40   40
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5

[[4]]$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10
[2,]   20   20   20   20   20
[3,]   30   30   30   30   30
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]   50   50   50   50   50


[[5]]
[[5]]$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   50   50   50   50   50
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5

[[5]]$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10
[2,]   20   20   20   20   20
[3,]   30   30   30   30   30
[4,]   40   40   40   40   40
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

---

You can try the code below

```
list2env(
  setNames(
    Map(
      function(x, r) {
        x[1, ] <- r
        x
      },
      list(A, B),
      list(B[1, ], A[1, ])
    ), c("A", "B")
  ),
  envir = .GlobalEnv
)
```

Comment: very good answer. Thank you. Is there any way to use apply to function f1 and matrix B, that is to switch the first row of A with all rows of B one at a time (a result of 5 new matrices B)? I tried to make your answer a new function, using apply or sapply or lapply, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`replace` seems to work without any intermediate

```
replace(A, cbind(1, 1:ncol(A)), B[1,])
replace(B, cbind(1, 1:ncol(A)), A[1,])
```

Note that once we do the assignment to the original object, the second assignment is not possible as the original object is changed

---

A clean way to swap is to create a temporary object and `rm` it

```
tmp <- A[1,]
A[1, ] <- B[1, ]
B[1, ] <- tmp
rm(tmp)
gc()
```

---

Or probably create a function, and do the swap inside the function, thus the activation record is deleted once it exit the function (as these are pass by value)

```
f1 <- function(a, b) {
       t1 <- a[1,]
       a[1,] <- b[1,]
       b[1,] <- t1
       return(list(a, b))
    }
list2env(setNames(f1(A, B), c('A', 'B')), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: @arkun the first option actually does not work, since A changes and so B cannot be obtained correctly, as you wrote. The second option actually uses an intermediate (what you wrote temporary object). How I can use apply to function f1 and matrix B, that is to switch the first row of A with all rows of B one at a time (a result of 5 new matrices B)?